# docker-compose limits are being ignored (not working)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yaml file like this setting memory limit for api service:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  api:
    image: someimage
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 128m
   // rest of config
```

Problem is that even after restarting docker-compose, recreating all containers etc still the limit of memory is not applied.
Running docker stats I see that there is no limit set

```
62951600a24c   api   0.02%     69.06MiB / 1.894GiB   3.56%     3.22MB / 1.55MB   2.63MB / 0B   23
```

So the limit shown from docker stats  is ~=2gb which is the maximum memory machine has instead of 128mb that I sepcified. My expectation is to have 128mb limit as that is what I set.

My docker-compose version

```
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

And docker version

```
docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

Comment: In non-Swarm mode, Compose completely ignores the `deploy:` section.  You need to use a `version: '2.x'` Compose file which has a different way to specify resource constraints that work with a local Docker.  The linked question has an example.

Comment: Hi, I am not using swarm mode. Is there a way to set limits when using `docker-compose up -d` ?

Comment: The question linked above has details on doing this, yes.